# how to combine 3rd party dll with own dll

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I'm creating a library TRSetup.dll in C#.
The project include some third party dll.
(eg: GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll, GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll, RemObjects.Hydra.dll)

I need to combine all the dll and create a single dll.

I'm using ilMerge to combine the dll.
The following command I'm using,

```
    ilMerge /out:MergedSetup.dll /targetplatform:v4,"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client" 
/lib: TRSetup.dll  Galasoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll Galasoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll RemObject.Hydra.dll
```

I can create a dll with the name MergedSetup.dll, But in runtime it is crashing.
How shall I merge these dll.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When is it "crashing"? What is happening? Any exceptions, code examples?

Comment: TRSetupWindow is a WPF form.
When I call the Constructor of the TRSetupWindow(), it is crashing.
I try to debug it, it is giving following exception.

`Could not load file or assembly 'TRSetup, Version=1.0.0.2228, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: The Constructor of the TRSetup has the InitializeComponent(), it is initialize the WPF GUI component, which is automaticallly generated

Answer (score 5):

That's know problem with WPF (and NHibernate, and many others which reference assembly by name) and ILMerge. Long story short after ILMerge there is no such assembly anymore, they all get injected into main assembly.

Try embedding instead of merging: LibZ (
http://libz.codeplex.com/) or Costura.Fody (https://github.com/Fody/Costura/)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of LibZ.

Cheers,

Comment: The reason I used Costura.Fody instead of LibZ is the support of embedding pdb for debugging.